# Django admin - remove "add another" button for a self-referential field

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a Django project that includes a model class with an optional self-referential ForeignKey field. A partial snippet:

```
class Site(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent_site = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

I'm using the Django admin site to create new objects. For this class' admin form I'd like to disable the "**Add another...**" button next to the `parent_site` field (i.e. when you're creating a new site, you can't open the popup to create another new site as the parent).

I can't remove `has_add_permission` from the user, as they need it to be in the current add view. I don't mind removing the function from both add and change views, but limiting removal to the add view would be helpful.

I haven't been able to work out how to use the Inline field classes to achieve this, or `formfield_for_foreignkey`, or a custom `ModelForm`. Anyone got a solution more elegant than using JavaScript on a customised form template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no css hacks add to admin class:

```
max_num=0
```

or try this in admin.py ( for older django versions):

```
class MODEL_ADMIN(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {'all': ('css/no-addanother-button.css',)}
```